# How can solve my issue with setwebhook telegram bot

Tags: php, bots, webhooks, telegram

Recently I had problem with setwebhook of telegram bot
I did this:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -sha256 -nodes -keyout YOURPRIVATE.key -x509 -days 365 -out YOURPUBLIC.pem -subj "/C=US/ST=New York/L=Brooklyn/O=Example Brooklyn Company/CN=YOURDOMAIN.EXAMPLE"
```

and this:

```
curl https://api.telegram.org/botxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/setWebhook \
-F "url=https://www.mywebsite.in.nf/test/bot1.php" \
-F "certificate=@/home/myUSER/YOURPUBLIC.pem"
```

and my own php file is:

```
$token = "xxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$telegram = urldecode ($json);
$results = json_decode($telegram);
$message = $results->message;
$text = $message->text;
$chat = $message->chat;
$user_id = $chat->id;
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$user_id.'&text='.$text;
file_get_contents($url);
```

When I send message to bot, it does nothing. I can't find the mistake, anyone had a similar problem??